# Unified Alignment For Lists

Tags: html, css

How can I create a list in html/css that displays data like this:

```
who:   him
where: there
what:  that
why:   because
```

so that it has a consistent horizontal alignment for the answers, even if it is not a monospaced font?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Unless you want to use a table you have to specify a fixed width for the left column (the most appropriate element in this case is a definition list).

Comment: i've used divs to separate the question/answer column, but i'd rather a better way.

Comment: I think a [*HTML Description List Element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) would be perfect here (semantically).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "li" make two classes in the css like so:

```
.question{
    clear:right;
    width: 50px;
}
.answer{
   float:left;
}
```

and of course:

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

it might be clear:left; not sure try both.

then apply class="question" to questions and class="answer" to answers.

you may also want to add:

```
margin:0;padding:0;list-decoration:none;
```

Comment: is there a way to make it adjust to the length of the question rather than a fixed width? that's what i'm really looking for.

Comment: @user2722162 im sorry i didnt quite catch that can you please spell that out more clearly? i thought you want the answer to start at the same spot always

Answer (score 0):

could use an unordered list with an `inline-block` `<span>` for the first column

```
<ul>
    <li><span>who:</span>him</li>
    <li><span>where:</span>there</li>
    <li><span>what:</span>that</li>
    <li><span>why:</span>because</li>
</ul>
```

```
ul, li {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
li span {display:inline-block;width:60px;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vs3EK/)

Comment: is there a way to make it adjust to the length of the question rather than a fixed width? that's what i'm really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><span>who:</span>him</li>
    <li><span>where:</span>there</li>
    <li><span>what:</span>that</li>
    <li><span>why:</span>because</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul, li {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
li span {display:inline-block;}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    max = 0;
    $('li span').each(function() {
        c_width = parseInt($(this).width());
        if (c_width > max) {
            max = c_width;
        }
    });
    $('li span').css('width',max);
});
```